# Is there a way to connect to a local pc via a gateway without having the gateway shine through?

Tags: ssh, gvfs, gateway

When I'm at work I can use **nautilus to navigate files** on other computers of the local network comfortably. Nautilus mounts the other computers file systems using **ssh (sftp via gvfs)**. However when I'm at home I **need to connect to a gateway (via ssh)** server for security reasons. From there I can ssh into the local computers. **This breaks nautilus ability to browse the files** as I can just see the gateway and there is no direct sftp link I could use in nautilus.

- **How can I use nautilus to browse files on machines of my work's local network from home?**
- **How do I need to configure the gateway to make that possible (If it's possible at all)?**

To make thinks worse I only have user (not root) priviliges on the gateway.

I strongly suspect there is no solution outside having our sys-admin installing a VPN, but AU has supprised me with clever solutions in the past.

#### Edit:

It was suggested to run `nautilus` on my work computer. I did so using X-forwading: `ssh -t -C -X gateway ssh -t -X me@workpc nautilus`. Unfortunately I get an error that says "Nautilus cannot handle sftp locations."

[image: Nautilus error message with X-Forwading]

Even if x-forwarding worked properly it would have to distinct disadvantages:

- Slow responding GUI
- No drag and drop of files to my local (=home) machine

So still looking for a better solution. Is there no such thing as ssh forwarding, so that the gateway just pushes all ssh requests to my work-pc?

Comment: Please explain what "connecting through a gateway" means....?

Comment: What is this gateway? How do you connect to it? What software/tools do you use?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was self explanatory. The gateway is a normal linux computer. I can use ssh to connect to it and from there to the other computer of the local network.

Comment: There seems to be an error in the ssh command you mentioned above. The line has two ssh commands but no reference to your work computer. Sorry, may be someone with more experience will have a better solution.

Comment: Ah, yes. The configuration my gateway uses an alias that inserts the work computer on its own. For clarification I added the `user@hostname` part

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the user@hostname issue. So if I understand you correctly, nautilus at workpc opens and you can browse files in workpc from homepc, but cannot sftp to **workpc-2** (login.leo3.uibk.ac.at) from workpc wihle remotely using nautilus. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. That's right.

Comment: This may be a long shot. Since you are using nautilus in workpc to sftp to workpc2 from within the office network, you may need to specify the local machine name rather than the full external url. Unless the full url (login.xxx.yyy.zzz.at) works when you are physically in front of workpc and connect from workpc to workpc2.

Comment: I'm using the same URL when I use at work. It's a bookmark I created at work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4336/discussion-between-user68186-and-con-f-use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your gateway, mount your **workpc**: `gvfs-mount sftp://username@workpc/`

In your PC at home, use Nautilus to connect to your **gateway** and access `~/.gvfs` on it: type `sftp://username@gateway/home/username/.gvfs` in the location bar and you'll see your **workpc** mounted there.

Comment: @con-f-use Did you test it? Did it work?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two possible solutions. Each involves running nautilus on the remote computers instead of your home computer.

**First**. If your gateway box can run nautilus remotely, use something like:

```
ssh -X gateway.company.com nautilus
```

This would start nautilus in the gateway (assuming it is installed) and display it on your home computer. Then you may be able to browse other computers in the LAN using sftp if you know their local host names or IP addresses.

**Second**. If the gateway does not have nautilus installed or for some reason sftp from within nautilus does not work when running on the gateway, you can try to run nautilus on one of the destination machines like this:

```
ssh -t -X gateway.company.com ssh -X computer.with.files.to.browse.local nautilus
```

This would open nautilus in the final remote destination "computer.with.files.to.browse.local" and display it on your home computer via the gateway.

See details at: https://serverfault.com/questions/149846/access-remote-server-with-nautilus-through-double-ssh-tunnel

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason my remote nautilus does not work properly (see the edit of my question).

Comment: You are welcome. Could you please tell us some details of what happens when you try to open the remote version of nautilus? Are you trying the first or the second method?

Comment: Since the gateway is a headless machine I'm using the second.